# what's the scope of the variable in *ngFor

Tags: angular

If I have for example a list that I'm using the ngFor. For example:

```
<li *ngFor="let contact of Contacts">
```

What's the scope of contact? It's mean - when I write let contact of Contacts , is it actually declares a new variable? Or, just for the purpose of the list?

And if it is declares a new variable - is it a reusable variable like any other variables? And if yes, then what is the scope? And what is the type of the variable? The type that was declare in the component? (In this case - the contacts).

I try to understand it.

Comment: In short, assuming 'Contacts' is an array of type 'T' so that `Contacts: T[]`, then 'contact' is an element of that array (varies for each iteration of the ngFor loop), of type 'T' accessible within whatever html-tag it was used on. Here, in your case accessible within `<li></li>`

Comment: scope would be from start of the html element to the end of current tag, in your case <li *ngFor="let contact of Contacts"> to </li>